# libusb_get_device_descriptor() always returns 0. How do I detect failure?

Tags: c, linux, libusb

Prior to version 1.0.16 of libusb, libusb_get_device_descriptor() would return 0 for success or a negative integer to indicate failure.  With version 1.0.16 and later, this function always returns 0.  How do I detect and figure out why I fail to get a descriptor now that that convenient means of figuring it out is gone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation explicitly states that

> Note since libusb-1.0.16, LIBUSB_API_VERSION >= 0x01000102, this function always succeeds.

This means you should never fail to get descriptor.

Comment: My problem is that I want to be able to tell why I'm unable to talk to a device.  Should I just check if NULL is returned from `libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid()` and forget about finding out why?

Comment: If you're already traversing a list of devices and querying descriptors for them, there's no need to do it for the second time (inside `libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid`). Just call `libusb_open` for the found device (after checking its vid/pid/etc. from descriptor), and it will return a meaningful error code you can analyze.